# (#12) adaccount/stats is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get report status from facebook using this

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/act_AD_ACCOUNT_ID/reportstats?data_columns=[%22campaign_id%22,%22impressions%22,%22spend%22,%22age%22,%22gender%22,%22cpc%22]&date_preset=yesterday&access_token=EXTENDED_TOKEN_OF_FACEBOOK_APP

by GET method.

I am getting an error as

> {
>
> "error": {
>   "message": "(#12) adaccount/reportstats is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher",
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "code": 12
>
> }
>
> }

I am admin of that account.I have checked ad account setting no version setting found, by default facebook app version is v2.4. So how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use v2.3, or use the `insights` edge as described at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/v2.4

> This insights edge consolidates functionality from /stats, /conversions, and /reportstats edges. It provides a single, consistent interface for insights.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adreportstats/v2.4

> ...refers to a feature that was removed after Marketing API v2.0.